# How to advice entity classes not spring beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

i'm looking to advice setters of entity classes using AspectJ on Spring Boot, but i found that only spring beans could be advised.

Is there any trick to advice setters of entity classes (for example), these entity classes could not be spring beans.

Comment: Not a trick but a normal solution is to not use proxy based AOP but use lead-time or compile time weaving of your aspects. A bit trickier to setup but it will work on any class.

Answer (score 2):

> only spring beans could be advised

Well, it's true in case you are using Spring AOP and not(!!!) AspectJ.

If replacing Spring AOP with AspectJ is an option, you can weave what ever you like by using `@Configurable`

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ajlib-other)
You can find the documentation that says that you can put Spring annotations like `@Transactional` on your non beans instances.

Comment: What does @Configurable have to do with AspectJ advising entity classes?

Comment: It's not specific to entity classes but for any class that is not a Spring bean.

Comment: I still don't get what the annotation has to do with AspectJ advising anything. Maybe I'm just thick, but my AspectJ uses pointcut definitions and advises, none of which require the use of a @Configurable annotation.

Comment: Yes, it is used for dependency injection on domain objects, which isn't what the OP is asking about because he wants to advise arbitrary methods.

Comment: OK, now I understand your question. I referred to the part that  @geogeek wrote about advising non beans classes.

Comment: Alright, might be a misinterpretation of what you meant by "replacing Spring AOP with AspectJ". I took that to mean as "use plain AspectJ". It might be a good idea to provide some links to the documentation of the feature you mention, so @geogeek can read up on it and see if it solves his problem.

Comment: Not only dependency injection (see my updated answer)